# How to write pandas.DataFrame data with array values back to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

[Pandas.DataFrame, I have this output data as a dataframe and i wanted to write back this data back to excel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdwBY.png)

[This is excel sheet format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCl9j.png)

I wanted to write dataframe row in excel cell, for example :- Kosten EK will goes in excel sheet D4, IRR mit Finanzierung will go in excel sheet D5. I have same dataframe in which Soll-SOC 1-12 value is single value not an array and it is working properly, but for this case because of array i could not write. how can i solve this?
I am using xlwings, xlwriter to write data back to excel

```
import  xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book(file_path) # wb = xw.Book(filename) would open an existing file
Working_Sheet = wb.sheets["sheet_name"] # activating working sheet
Working_Sheet.range('D4:D15').options(index=False,header=False).value = Data[20000][0.25]
```

Comment: How do you want the array in Soll-SOC 1-12 to be outputted into Excel?  A single list in one cell or across multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to convert to a `pd.DataFrame` object.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
import  xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book(file_path) # wb = xw.Book(filename) would open an existing file
Working_Sheet = wb.sheets["sheet_name"] # activating working sheet
Working_Sheet.range('D4:D15').options(convert=pd.DataFrame, index=False,header=False).value = Data[20000][0.25]
```

Comment: sorry. it is not working. I am getting this error ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()